# What is the best approach, deactivating constraints or changing the priority?

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout, anchor

I don't understand quick well, the AutoLayout. Since I'm trying to do multiple animations with some UIElements, do I need to deactivate/activate the constraints or should I use the priority of the anchors?

Comment: It's hard to answer such a broad question. Deactivating constraints removes them from the view hierarchy, which will cause them to be deallocated unless you maintain another strong reference to them. Lowering their priority will let you leave them attached to the views they modify, so that's probably the better option.  I usually do animations by modifying the constant value on constraints, and don't need to remove/reprioritize constraints as part of animations very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could watch [WWDC video about Auto Layout tech](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/). The core of auto layout is [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). It use [constraint solver](http://www.constraintsolving.com/solvers) to solve those linear problem.

As the image from [WiKi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), those rules of auto layout is as the same as the `Problem constraints`, and there is ONLY a global optimal to solve those constraints. If no global optimal to solve those constraints, then those rules have conflicts.

[image: WiKi image]

---

From WWDC video, I had learned to define groups of constraints to implement animations, by deactivating A group, and then activate B group. Sometimes I like to modify properties of constraints to implement animation effect. If the approach make my codes clean and easy to understand, then I adopt that approach.

#### property: isActive

[Apple official document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1527000-isactive)

Auto Layout constraints could be bound to `@IBOutlet` from `xib` and `storyboard`.  `NSLayoutConstraint` has a property named [isActive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1527000-isactive). You could define groups of constraints. But before you active / de-active constraints, always do de-active first. In order to avoid conflicts of constrains. I got this from WWDC video.

#### property: constant, multiplier

- [Apple doc: constant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526928-constant)
- [Apple doc: multiplier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526920-multiplier)

You could change the [multiplier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526920-multiplier) and [constant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526928-constant) of a constraint in runtime. After updating properties of a constraint, call [setNeedsupdateConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622450-setneedsupdateconstraints) and [updateConstraintsifNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622595-updateconstraintsifneeded) of `UIView` to apply those changes.